# Postgresql driver not found for the hive-metastore in Spark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I have done two things to install the `postgresql` driver for use by spark:

- copied the driver jar into the `$SPARK_HOME/jars` directory:

```
$ll $SPARK_HOME/jars/post*
-rw-r--r--  1 stephenboesch  staff  1046274 Nov 10 14:44 /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec/jars/postgresql-42.5.0.jar
```

- added the jar to `SparkConf`:

```
spark = (SparkSession.builder
    .appName(appName)
    .config('spark.jars','/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec/jars/postgresql-42.5.0.jar')
    .master(master)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate())
```

But when running the `pyspark` script the driver is not found?

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `enableHiveSupport()` kills it .. ?  By commenting it out now it all works

```
spark = (SparkSession.builder
    .appName(appName)
    .config('spark.jars','/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec/jars/postgresql-42.5.0.jar')
    .master("local")
    # .enableHiveSupport()   #  Not sure why enabling this loses the driver..
    .getOrCreate())
```